# ¿Como extraer el contenido de un blockquote?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Intento extraer el contenido de un blockquote con el dom  y al ejecutarlo me dice undefined.
el código es el siguiente

```
let texto_control = document.querySelector("blockquote").value;
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = texto_control;
```

Cual es el error

Answer (score 4):

[Blockquote](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote) no tiene un atributo `value`. Entiendo que quieres su contenido encerrado entre `<blockquote></blockquote>` por lo tanto esto te puede valer:

```
let texto_control = document.querySelector("blockquote").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

La propiedad que necesitas utilizar es:

- [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) si queres texto plano
- [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) si queres el HTML

#### Ejemplo:

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let texto_control = document.querySelector("blockquote").innerText; // Texto plano
  document.querySelector(".text").innerHTML = texto_control;
})
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <strong>Hola</strong>, como estas?
</blockquote>
<br />
<button class="btn">Obtener</button>
<textarea class="text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

lo arregle con `.textContent`.

saludos

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).